# Do all values of $\zeta (s)$ follow from the Dirichlet series definition of $\zeta (s)$?

Tags: complex-analysis, riemann-zeta, analytic-continuation

If we define $\zeta (s)$ by
$$\zeta (s)\overset{\text{def}}{=}\sum_{n\gt 0}n^{-s},\, \operatorname{Re}s\gt 1,$$
does it follow from the definition that e.g. $\zeta (-1)=-\frac{1}{12}$?

Or is it necessary to use
$$\zeta (s) \overset{\text{def}}{=} \begin{cases} \sum_{n\gt 0}n^{-s} &\mbox{if } \operatorname{Re}s\gt 1 \\
2^s\pi ^{s-1}\sin\frac{\pi s}{2}\,\Gamma (1-s)\sum_{n\gt 0}n^{s-1}& \mbox{if }\operatorname{Re}s\le 0\\ \frac{1}{1-2^{1-s}}\sum_{n\gt 0}(-1)^{n+1}n^{-s}& \mbox{otherwise}\end{cases}$$
and then say that $\zeta (-1)=-\frac{1}{12}$?

Comment: The usual definition is that $\zeta(s)$ is the analytic continuation of the Dirichlet series, and that is enough to get $\zeta(-1).$ Note your second definition is not enough - is does include the cases where the real part of $s$ is in $[0,1].$

Comment: Oh, I see where's the problem now.

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3159749/8530

Comment: $$\lim_{k\to \infty } \, \left(\sum _{n=1}^k \frac{1}{n^s}+\frac{k^{1-s}}{s-1}-\frac{k^{-s}}{2}+\frac{s}{12 k^{s+1}}\right)=-\frac{1}{12}$$ when $s=-1$