# Asymptotic expansion of divergent Riemann sums

Tags: sequences-and-series, analysis, riemann-zeta

For $s \in ]0;1[$, the Riemann serie $\displaystyle \sum_{k>0}\frac{1}{k^s}$ diverges and we have the more precise asymptotic expansion :  $$\sum_{k=1}^n\frac{1}{k^s} = \frac{n^{1-s}}{1-s}+ \zeta(s)+ \underset{n\to+\infty}{o}(1)$$

where $\zeta$ is the analytic continuation of the Riemann zeta function to $\mathbb{C}-\left\{1\right\}$.

I was wondering :

- For $s\le 0$, is there an analogous formula ? By analogous, i mean something that relates the behavior of the Riemann sum $\displaystyle \sum_{k=1}^{n}k^{-s}$ when $n\to +\infty$ to the value of $\zeta(s)$ ?
- For $0<s<1$, what can be said about the following terms in the asymptotic development above ? Are they related to other "well-known" functions ?

Thanks,

Comment: See https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4024675

Comment: Related: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3159749/8530