# A Proof of $H_x=\int_0^1\frac{1-t^x}{1-t}dt$

Tags: calculus

Well I found this equation in my old notes and I remember I proved in a scratch paper but I forget it how.
Where $H_x$ is the harmonic series til $x$.
I remember there is trick to expand $\frac{1-t^x}{1-t}$ to a sum in someway then bring the integral inside and then we will get the harmonic series.

Comment: Please define $H_x$

Comment: Is the $x$ integer?

Comment: Connected : https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3641389/305862

Comment: @VincentBatens I edited it. Should I put in the title, too??

Comment: @Gary Ty. I got it now. Should I delete the question 'cause it  is a kind of duplicate?

Comment: yes, it is also already flagged as a duplicate and will be probably closed soon anyway.

Comment: Yes, good idea.

Comment: @Gary Not really a duplicate : here $x$ is a real number, whereas in the mentionned question it is an integer.

Comment: @JeanMarie I think its an integer since $H_x$ is defined as the harmonic series till $x$.